# Cannot update variable in Java

Tags: java

I can't update `min` variable. Can you explain to me what is wrong?

```java
public class Sum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(GetMin(1,5));
    }

    public static int GetMin(int a, int b) {
        int min;
        int max;
        if (a == b) {
            return a;
        }
        if (a > b) {
            min = b;
            max = a;
        }
        if (a < b) {
            min = a;
            max = b;
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

`min` should be 1 but this error occurs:

> error: variable min might not have been initialized

Comment: The compiler (or your IDE) is not smart enough to realize that you have covered all the possibilities. I know it's impossible, but if `a` is not equal to `b` and `a` is not less than `b` and `a` is not greater than `b`, then `min` will not be assigned a value. Consider using `else if` rather than separate `if` statements.

Comment: why would you want the `min`? just return the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Problem

With your actual structure, java can't ensure that `min` will always be initialized

##### Solution

You need to some `else if` and `else` to prove java that `min` will be defined

```
public static int GetMin(int a, int b) {
    int min;
    int max;
    if (a == b) {
        return a;
    } else if (a > b) {
        min = b;
        max = a;
    } else {
        min = a;
        max = b;
    }
    return min;
}
```

As when `a==b` and when `a<b` you return `a`, you could initialize `min` with `a`

```
public static int GetMin(int a, int b) {
    int min = a;
    if (a > b) {
        min = b;
    } 
    return min;
}
```

Or use ternary operator

```
public static int GetMin(int a, int b) {
    return a > b ? b : a;
}
```

Comment: What about: `return a > b ? b : a` ?

Answer (score -1):

upd: in discussion we resolved that the reason is in Java Language Specification (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf), not in `javac`.

***Overall as a solution you can initialize `min`, `max` variables or use `if-then-else` expression***

I think that it is bug of compiler, because in any case of this execution we will get minimum value. As a solution you can write so:

```
public static int GetMin(int a, int b) {
    int min;
    int max;
    if (a == b) {
        return a;
    } else if (a > b) {
        min = b;
        max = a;
    } else {
        min = a;
        max = b;
    }
    return min;
}
```

Or simply use:

```
public static int GetMin(int a, int b) {
    return a > b ? b : a;
}
```

Comment: This is not a compiler bug; the compiler cannot infer that the three `if`-conditions cover all possibilities.

Comment: IF is not exaustive, so the compiler has no way of knowing if you covered all the cases or not. But we cannot say it is a compiler bug :)

Comment: There is a spec. The spec dictates precisely how the compiler is supposed to figure out so-called 'definite assignment'. This spec clearly states that the compiler is _not_ to infer that `min` is DA at the return statement. Thus, when you say "I think that it is a bug", no it isn't. At worst, it's a crappy spec. (I think the spec is fine here, just, _if_ you want to argue this is something OpenJDK should address, then the thing to fix is the spec. Not `javac`).

Comment: Tried on several JVMs, you are right about JLS: same error on each one. So the reason of such behaviour in JLS https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf. 

Also tried to parse JLS about if (§16.2.2) and uninitialized values (§14.4, §14.13), but it is really hard to understand :) 

So solution will be just to initialize `min`, `max` or use `if-else-then`